# permalinks is not working in xampp/localhost server on windows 7

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, xampp, permalinks

When I click over permalinks from the wordpress admin it creates .htaccess file in the root folder automatically and then wordpress site stops working with the browser error **server error 500** I have made following settings in httpd.conf and my mod_rewrite is working as per php.ini displays.

**httpd.conf SETTINGS**

```
<Directory "E:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

```
<Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options All

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

---

**HTACCESS FILE CODE**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xampp/ozi-tech/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /xampp/ozi-tech/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: what web server u uses for run wordpress

Comment: :rash111 apache server as it is included in the xampp server

Comment: Did you take a look at apache error log ?

Comment: you want to remove index.php or anything else

Answer (score 6):

If your project is located on 
*E:/xampp/htdocs/ozi-tech/* 
then you need to specify the path starting from the localhost.

```
E:/xampp/htdocs/  === localhost === /
```

You just need to change **RewriteBase** and **RewriteRule** in the .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ozi-tech/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ozi-tech/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: worked for me just add base folder before index.php line,.. like Sergey showed: /ozi-tech/index.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

I did struggle to resolve this issue but the main thing i found is my local server which does not support htaccess URL rewrite scene so I uploaded the same code on ftp account and gets relief online.

I wonder if we could allow URL rewrite in local server though I have uncomment the URL rewrite module in xampp server but still unable to work in local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The code above will get rid of the .php extension, thus giving you say index instead of index.php. And yes it works on localhost and nearly all hosting companies include it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem using XAMPP and with my project in a different directory than XAMPP's default project directory.

I solved it by adding: `AllowOverride All` *outside* of the *specific* `<Directory>` tag in **httpd.conf**.

So, in the main `<Directory />` tag itself, like this:

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

If you have more strict security needs, definitely figure out how to `AllowOverride` within a specific directory, but allowing override on all directories was a quick fix for me.